# Asp.net Core SignalR hub check if a connection is alive Than text to them

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

Hi I am new in SignalR asp.net core  I have a hub to send the message to Specific User Id Admin & client .I want all user admin level revive message when client send the message.So i have a admin user list where client send the message .Problem is how we identify which admin is live because when i send the message to all admin if any admin not connected/live with hub then my code go to error i need to identify which user is live 
How i identify in asp.net core signalR?
how i check this user is available in asp.net core signalR?
here my code block where i send the message to user

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string userId, string message, string[] myArray)
    {
       foreach(var s in myArray)
        {               
            var connections =  _userConnectionManager.GetUserConnections(s);
            if (connections != null && connections.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var connectionId in connections)
                {
                    await _notificationUserHubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("sendToUser", message, User.Identity.Name);//send to user 
                }
            }
        }            
        //get the connection from the 
        return View();
    }
```

here is java script function to call the above code when click on button

```
  $("#sendButton").click(function () {
        var useridd = document.getElementById("userIdd").value;
        var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;
        alert(msg);
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
             url: "/ComplaintSystem/ChatRoom/Index",
            data: {userId : useridd, message : msg, myArray: myArray},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

In myArray revive all admin users where i send the message.

Comment: You can easily create an ```Dictionary``` that will add to it the admins and the connectionId of that admin, and then when you need to send message to admin just look up for that list.

Comment: Yes ,I have a list where i see the list of connectionId ...Can you see in above code ,in Index method have construtor string[] myArray ,In that array store all admin connection ids but if anyone is not connected with signalR than my code goes to exception of that statement {var connections =  _userConnectionManager.GetUserConnections(s);}   that way i asking how to check connection who is available to send the message.

Comment: You mean if your array list is empty because no one is connected?

Comment: No, In my  has multiple connection ids.Just i want to check all ids which is connected which is not connected where i need to send the message.If i send the message which is not connected with SignalR ,My code throw the exception that way i want to check before sending the message.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. So you have the list of connectionId, you should add the this list only the connected users and remove them when they disconnect, so when you need to find some connectionId, you just need to lookup for your list.

Comment: Yes i have a list of connection id ,Yes i want to add the this list only connected users and also i need to remove them when they disconnect,so how i check which user is disconnect.

Comment: You just overide the method ```OnDisconnectAsync``` and there you have the user id that is disconnecting and remove that id from your list.